# Pathing issues when I try to set my .htaccess file to my main file location. (cpanel)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, path, cpanel

I'm trying to set up the base path/file for my site on my server.  The file I want to load is in my document root within the following path:

> /src/pages/views/index.php

I'm trying to get my .htaccess file to point to this location by default.  I have tried doing this

```
DirectoryIndex /src/pages/views/index.php
```

which does automatically route to my index file, but then all relative paths in my site no longer work.  (My url bar shows just 'mywebsite.com')

If I don't have anything in my .htaccess file, then I go to mywebsite.com (which shows me the root directories) and manually click my way into the directory that I want, everything works just fine and there are no pathing issues (my url bar now shows 'mywebsite.com/src/pages/views/').

By "pathing issues", I mean all of my imported files (javascript, css, etc) are 404ing because it can't find the path.

Is there a way to actually make it so that when a user types in :

```
mywebsite.com
```

it will actually redirect them to the proper path? :

```
mywebsite.com/src/pages/views/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/src/pages/views/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mywebsite\.com$ /mywebsite.com/src/pages/views/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```